# How to calculate the difference of HH:MM:SS between two dates in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table abc as:

```
-- start_time          |end_time             | total_time_taken
-- 27.05.2020 00:52:48 |27.05.2020 02:08:33  |
```

I want to set the value of `total_time_taken` as the difference of `end_time-start_time.` in the format `"HH:MM:SS"`.I searched the similar topic but didnot find the exact answer.

My expected output is like : `01:44:12 (HH:MM:SS)`

So,i tried :

```
SELECT To_Char(end_time,'HH24:MM:SS'),To_Char(start_time,'HH24:MM:SS'),
To_Char(end_time,'HH24:MM:SS')-To_Char(start_time,'HH24:MM:SS') FROM abc;
```

The datatypes of **start_time,end_time,total_time_taken** is `DATE.`Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: And in case of more than 24 hours you'd expect a result like 123:44:55?

Comment: no my procedure runs like a 1 to 2 hour so,i needed that. it doesnot cross a day

Comment: Okay. Returning an interval seems best suited for the task. This can be achieved by subtracting timestamsps as shown in Littlefoot's answer. The DATE data type is much older than TIMESTAMP and does not return an interval for that reason. It returns the difference in days instead. This decimal number can be converted with `NUMTODSINTERVAL`: `numtodsinterval(end_time - start_time, 'day')`.

Comment: ok thank you for sharing ur knowledge !!! cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cast those dates as timestamps, you can easily subtract them and see relatively nice result:

```
SQL> with test (st, et) as
  2    (select to_date('27.05.2020 00:52:48', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  3            to_date('27.05.2020 02:08:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  4     from dual
  5    )
  6  select cast(et as timestamp) - cast(st as timestamp) diff
  7  from test;

DIFF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 01:15:45.000000

SQL>
```

If you want to format it as you wanted (note that `mm` format mask is for **months**; `mi` is for **minutes**), then you could do some *extracting* - again from timestamp (won't work for date):

```
SQL> with test (st, et) as
  2    (select to_date('27.05.2020 00:52:48', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  3            to_date('27.05.2020 02:08:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  4     from dual
  5    ),
  6  diff as
  7    (select cast(et as timestamp) - cast(st as timestamp) diff
  8     from test
  9    )
 10  select extract(hour   from diff) ||':'||
 11         extract(minute from diff) ||':'||
 12         extract(second from diff) diff
 13  from diff;

DIFF
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1:15:45

SQL>
```

You can further make it pretty (e.g. two digits for hours, using `LPAD` function). Or, you can even write your own function which will actually work on difference of `DATE` datatype values, do some calculations (using `trunc` function, subtractions, whatnot), but the above looks pretty *elegant* if compared to a *home-made function*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Littlefoot is perfectly fine. This answer is just to show there is more than one way to get the result.

First, we can subtract one date from another and get the difference in days, then convert that difference to an interval.

```
with test (st, et) as
 (select to_date('27.05.2020 00:52:48', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
         to_date('27.05.2020 02:08:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  from dual
 )
select numtodsinterval(et-st, 'day') diff
from test;
```

Then, since we can't control interval formatting directly, we can add `DIFF` to an arbitrary date and then use built-in date formatting.

```
with test (st, et) as
 (select to_date('27.05.2020 00:52:48', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
         to_date('27.05.2020 02:08:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  from dual
 )
select to_char(date '1-1-1' + numtodsinterval(et-st, 'day'), 'hh24:mi:ss') diff
from test;

DIFF    
--------
01:15:45
```